# What is the default value for an Enum type instance variable in Java?

Tags: java, enums

This is the sample code I have:

```
enum A {
    A,
}

class TestA {
    A a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TestA testA = new TestA();
        System.out.println(testA.a);
        System.out.println(testA.a.A);
    }
}
```

Which will print:

```
null
A
```

If the default value for an uninitialized instance Enum variable is null, how does accessing an instance of an Enum work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A.A is a static variable. It's a bad idea, but authorized, to access static variable of a class using a variable referring to an instance of that class, even if it's null. That's not limited to enums:

```
Integer i = null;
System.out.println(i.MAX_VALUE);
```

runs fine. But it should really be written as

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 4):

Enum constants are essentially static members, so they obey the exact same rules as static members.

The reason it works is exactly the reason why `((System) null).out` will not cause an NPE, because its turned into a static member access which does not use the `null` in any way.